# 20.04 to 20.10 Upgrade made apt autoremove want to delete everything!

Tags: apt, 20.04, xfce, 20.10, ubuntu-studio

I recently upgraded my install of Ubuntu Studio from 20.04 to 20.10

I know it has been recommended to reinstall this particular upgrade, however, as I wanted to keep Xfce (rather than switching to KDE) and didn't want to have to bother setting up my computer and syncing all of my files again, I decided to upgrade instead.

The upgrade seemed to have worked, however, I am now greeted with this in my apt autoremove, and I am pretty sure that a lot of these packages are quite important, for example it seems to want to remove most of Xfce.
[image]

Or if you prefer to read it as text:

```
    app-install-data-partner brltty brltty-x11 bsdmainutils calendar calf-plugins catfish coinor-libcbc3 coinor-libcgl1 coinor-libclp1 coinor-libcoinmp1v5
  coinor-libcoinutils3v5 coinor-libosi1v5 digikam-data digikam-private-libs dpf-plugins dpf-plugins-dssi drumkv1 enchant espeak-ng-data fuseiso g++-9 gigolo
  gnome-system-tools gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gtk2-engines indicator-common indicator-messages ippusbxd language-selector-gnome libastro1 libboost-filesystem1.67.0
  libboost-system1.67.0 libbrlapi0.7 libcaf-openmpi-3 libcapi20-3 libcdio18 libcfitsio8 libcoarrays-openmpi-dev libcollada-dom2.4-dp0 libdc1394-22 libdns-export1109
  libdotconf0 libdvdread7 libebml4v5 libenchant1c2a libespeak-ng1 libevent-dev libevent-extra-2.1-7 libevent-openssl-2.1-7 libexo-1-0 libffi7 libffi7:i386 libgeos-3.8.0
  libgsoap-2.8.91 libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgtkspell0 libgwengui-gtk3-0 libhogweed5 libhogweed5:i386 libhwloc-dev libibverbs-dev libicu66
  libicu66:i386 libilmbase24 libjson-c4 libkaccounts1 libkf5akonadi-data libkf5akonadicontact-data libkf5akonadicontact5abi1 libkf5akonadicore-bin
  libkf5akonadicore5abi2 libkf5akonadiprivate5abi2 libkf5akonadiwidgets5abi1 libkf5calendarcore5abi2 libkf5contacteditor5 libkf5mime-data libkf5mime5abi2
  liblensfun-data-v1 liblensfun1 libllvm10 libllvm10:i386 liblua5.1-0 libmarblewidget-qt5-28 libmatroska6v5 libmpdec2 libnettle7 libnettle7:i386 libnl-3-dev
  libnl-route-3-dev libnuma-dev liboobs-1-5 libopenexr24 libopenmpi-dev libosmesa6 libpcaudio0 libpcre2-32-0 libplacebo7 libpoppler97 libproj15 libprotobuf-lite17
  libprotobuf17 libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libqhull7 libqpdf26 libqt5serialport5 libqtav1 libqtavwidgets1 libreoffice-gtk3 libsane
  libshp2 libsrt1 libstdc++-9-dev libusrsctp1 libwebsockets15 libx264-155 libx264-155:i386 libx265-179 libx265-179:i386 libx86emu2 libzita-convolver3
  lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings lsp-plugins marble-plugins marble-qt-data mousepad ncal numix-blue-gtk-theme numix-gtk-theme opencv-data openmpi-bin openmpi-common
  parole pidgin-otr popularity-contest python-backports.functools-lru-cache python-bs4 python-dbus python-gi python-html5lib python-lxml python-numpy
  python-pkg-resources python-six python-soupsieve python-webencodings python2 python2-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal python3-entrypoints qt5-gtk2-platformtheme
  qt5-style-plugin-cleanlooks qt5-style-plugin-motif qt5-style-plugin-plastique qt5-style-plugins qt5ct ristretto samplv1 sound-icons speech-dispatcher
  speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng synthv1 system-tools-backends ttf-summersby ubuntustudio-controls wine-stable-amd64 xbrlapi xcursor-themes
  xfburn xfce4-cpugraph-plugin xfce4-dict xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-netload-plugin xfce4-panel-profiles xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-systemload-plugin
  xfce4-verve-plugin xfce4-weather-plugin xfce4-xkb-plugin xfpanel-switch xubuntu-community-wallpapers xubuntu-community-wallpapers-focal
```

So my questions are:

1. Will removing any of these packages mess up my install?
2. How do I remove them from being autoremoved, and generally fix this issue?

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help!

Comment: Please do not post images of text. We prefer that you copy/paste the actual text, properly formatted, into your question.

Comment: The upgrade will switch you from XFCE to KDE, as that is what occurs with Ubuntu Studio installs from 20.04 (XFCE) to 20.10 (*most of* KDE). I'm not a Ubuntu Studio user, and can't read your picture of text (*not easily*), but I'd just let it happen, then fix it after reboot & I'm in 20.10 (login via text terminal only, not GUI & re-install like user535733 suggests; I may not use the same package, but I'd do more homework on differences, what was removed etc before I decided; their use of *Ubuntu Studio installer* on any desktop wasn't dropped). I would expect the end result to be good.

Comment: I'll edit the post to feature the packages as text.

Comment: Try installing the `xubuntu-desktop` package BUT, as @user535733 said, you'll end with a Frankenbuntu. Ubuntu Studio `20.10` only supports KDE+Plasma. If you want Sudio+XFCE, you need to stay in 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Ubuntu 20.10 Release Announcement](https://ubuntustudio.org/2020/10/ubuntu-studio-20-10-released/):

> Due to the change in desktop environment this release, direct upgrades to Ubuntu Studio 20.10 are not supported. We recommend a clean install for this release:
>
> Backup your home directory (/home/{username})
> Install Ubuntu Studio 20.10
> Copy the contents of your backed-up home directory to your new home directory.

What you are experiencing is expected behavior. Since you didn't follow the developers' advice (yet), you may encounter other issues.

Comment: This doesn't answer my questions.
I want to be able to service and fix my own system without having to constantly reinstall.
So, do you know if removing any of these packages will break a typical Ubuntu install? And how can I remove packages from the autoremove list?

Comment: @AdLinux You don't need to "constantly" reinstall it, just once.

Comment: You are asking for support after doing an action that is *specifically not supported*. This answer is intended to guide you back to the marked path.